# Why is django admin not showing "currently" value of ImageField?

Tags: python, django, linux

I'm facing an issue when deploying a django app in other machine. In my local machine is working fine, but in a linux machine is not showing the (Currently) current value of ImageField. Both environments have django 1.11.

The model:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = ("Empresa")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500, verbose_name="nombre")
    nit = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="nit")
    address = models.CharField(max_length=500, verbose_name="dirección", blank=True, null=True)
    telephone = models.CharField(max_length=15, verbose_name="teléfono", blank=True, null=True)
    cellphone = models.CharField(max_length=15, verbose_name="celular", blank=True, null=True)
    legal_representative = models.CharField(max_length=500, verbose_name="representante legal", blank=True, null=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='company/img', verbose_name="imagen", blank=True, null=True)
    photo_thumbnail1 = models.ImageField(upload_to='company/img', verbose_name="imagen 250x250", blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

The admin:

```
class CompanyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ('photo_thumbnail1',)
    list_display = ('id','name', 'nit', 'address','telephone','cellphone','legal_representative',)

    def render_change_form(self, request, context, *args, **kwargs):
        # Just to show the photo url while rendering
        print('rendering')
        print(vars(kwargs['obj']))
        if kwargs['obj'].photo:
            print(kwargs['obj'].photo.url)
        if kwargs['obj'].photo_thumbnail1:
            print(kwargs['obj'].photo_thumbnail1.url)
        return super(CompanyAdmin, self).render_change_form(request, context, args, kwargs)
```

In my local machine, I can see the the current value for Photo when I previously saved:
[image: Change form in local machine]

In linux machine, it is not showing the current value as if there is no image saved for this field. But I made sure it is getting the value when rendering by printing in console the urls:

[image]

[image]

Please, if you have any idea what can i do, it would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Is the database same, in both machines ?

Comment: Hi Bijoy, it is postgres 9.6 in both machines.